# Confused in using the ports for trunking mode

Tags: cisco, trunk

[image]

The ports are as follows:
for the switch on the left side the upper port is `fa0/1`, below it is `fa 1/1` and below `fa1/1` is `fa2/1`.  For the switch in the middle the left port is fa0/1 and the right port is `fa 1/1`. For the switch on the right side, the upper port is `fa1/1` below it `fa2/1` and below `fa2/1` is `fa3/1`.

In the diagram below, when configuring trunk mode will I give the following commands:

S1

```
interface range fa0/1, fa1/1
switchport mode trunk
no shutdown
end
```

S2:

```
interface range fa 1/1, fa2/1, fa3/1
switchport mode trunk
no shutdown
end
```

S3:

```
interface range fa 1/1, fa2/1, fa3/1
switchport mode trunk
no shutdown
end
```

If not then can you please mention the correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zac67 is right. Use the `switchport mode access` when you connect a port to a client end device ( PC, tel, etc) and use the trunk mode for connection between switches.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want trunk mode on the client ports - put those in access mode with the desired VLAN. You need to put the switch-to-switch ports in trunk mode.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Trunking towards a client doesn't make sense. Trunking in between switches does. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Quora.com says

> 'A trunk port is a port that is assigned to carry traffic for all the
>   VLANs that are accessible by a specific switch, a process known as
>   trunking. Trunk ports mark frames with unique identifying tags –
>   either 802.1Q tags or Inter-Switch Link (ISL) tags – as they move
>   between switches.'

If you want to communicate between switch and client those ports are called access ports. But If you want to connect two switches which contain vlans, you need to carry vlan information. Ports which are used to transmit vlan details are called trunk port. You don't want to exchange vlan information between client device and switch. Vlan information exchange only between switches. Therefore you need to configure trunk port between switches.

Answer (score 2):

The ports connected on computers must be Access ports because they dont need to carry Vlan information. Type this command **switchport mode access** on those links directly attached to PCs. The ports connected to switches must be trunk **switchport mode trunk** because those ones need to carry Vlan information from all the Vlans therefore the connection between the Switches must be trunk (only those ports).